# Uploading a file held in React state to AWS S3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, amazon-s3, next.js

I have a `NextJS` app that sends files from the front-end via an `API Route` to `AWS S3`. I encounter problems when trying to upload an `.MP3` file that is recorded on the front-end, by the user.

The file is held in state:

```
const [audioFile, setAudioFile] = useState(null)
```

The audio is recorded by the [`mic-recorder-to-mp3`](https://github.com/closeio/mic-recorder-to-mp3) component.

This is the function triggered by the `upload-btn`:

```
  const submitVoiceMemo = async () => {
    const filename = encodeURIComponent(audioFile.name)
    const res = await fetch(`/api/upload-url?file=${filename}`)
    const { url, fields } = await res.json()
    const formData = new FormData()

    Object.entries({ ...fields, audioFile }).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      formData.append(key, value)
    })

    const upload = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: formData
    })

    if (upload.ok) {
      console.log('Uploaded successfully!')
    } else {
      console.error('Upload failed.')
      console.error()
    }
```

- The upload triggers a `400 error (Bad Request)`.
- **I'm happy to provide more code to debug**.
- The region is set in the `API Route` to `'us-east-2'` (which is the region of the bucket).
- It's not returning a `CORS` Error, so I 'think' that CORS is correctly parameterised.

`console.log(upload)`:

```
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/waveforms', redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
type: "cors"
url: "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/waveforms"
[[Prototype]]: Response
```

Here is the `upload-url` route:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    aws.config.update({
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_1,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      region: 'us-east-2',
      signatureVersion: 'v4'
    })

    const s3 = new aws.S3()
    const post = await s3.createPresignedPost({
      Bucket: 'waveforms',
      Fields: {
        key: `voicememo/${req.query.file}`,
        ACL: 'public-read',
        ContentType: 'audio/mpeg'
      },
      Expires: 60,
      Conditions: [
        ['content-length-range', 0, 1048576]
      ]
    })

    console.log(post)

    res.status(200).json(post)

    } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: e.message })
  }
}
```

This is the `stop-btn` function that stores the audio to state `onClick()`:

```
const [blobURL, setBlobUrl] = useState(null)

...


const stopRecording = () => {
    recorder.current
      .stop()
      .getMp3()
      .then(([buffer, blob]) => {
        const file = new File(buffer, 'audio.mp3', {
          type: blob.type,
          lastModified: Date.now()
        })
        const newBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        setBlobUrl(newBlobUrl)
        setIsRecording(false)
        setAudioFile(file)
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of upload URL? There must be more information provided.

Comment: I'm not sure you are doing things correctly, but it's not easy to debug with just that code. The 400 comes from s3, so I guess you are sending a wrong body with your upload, I think s3 bucket wants a blob or a stream, not a FormData instance.

Comment: Hi @ErmiyaEskandary, I updated the question with the `API Route`.

Comment: @CesarePolonara I also hold `blobURL` in state (before its converted into an `MP3` file. I could try uploading that?

Comment: @WΔ_ Yes you can upload blobs, try that :)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I tried storing the `blob` in state and sending that to the `API route`, it registers a file in S3, but the file isn't playable :/ I couldn't destructure `req.body` so I sent the whole string... is their perhaps some way to format it, e.g. via createReadStream, I wonder...

Comment: @WΔ_ So that's now a different question :) please delete this one and create a new one with the exact code you're using

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71725986/uploading-a-blob-held-in-state-to-aws-s3.