# Uploading a Blob held in State to AWS S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js

I have implemented a `mic-recorder-to-mp3` component in a `ReactJS` `NextJS` app which stores a voice-memo recorded in the browser by the user and saves the resulting `blob` to React `state`, as well as a resulting `MP3` to `state` as well.

I am struggling to upload either the `blob` or the `MP3` file to `AWS S3` - the problem is evident in that I cannot parse the `req.body` string which is received by the `API`.

Here is some code! This is the function that stores the raw audio as `state`:

```
const [audioBlob, setAudioBlob] = useState(null)
const [blobURL, setBlobUrl] = useState(null)
const [audioFile, setAudioFile] = useState(null)


const stopRecording = () => {
    recorder.current
      .stop()
      .getMp3()
      .then(([buffer, blob]) => {
        const file = new File(buffer, 'audio.mp3', {
          type: blob.type,
          lastModified: Date.now()
        })
        setAudioBlob(blob)
        const newBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        setBlobUrl(newBlobUrl)
        setIsRecording(false)
        setAudioFile(file)
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }
```

And this is the function that sends the `payload` to the `API`:

```
  const submitVoiceMemo = async () => {
    const filename = encodeURIComponent(audioFile)    
    const res = await fetch(`/api/upload-url?file=${filename}`)
    const { url, fields } = await res.json()
    const formData = new FormData()

    Object.entries({ ...fields, audioFile }).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      formData.append(key, value)
    })
    const upload = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: formData
    })
    if (upload.ok) {
      console.log('Uploaded successfully!')
    } else {
      console.error('Upload failed.')
      console.error()
    }
  }
```

This is the `upload-url` `API` Route:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    aws.config.update({
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_1,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      region: 'us-east-2',
      signatureVersion: 'v4'
    })

    const s3 = new aws.S3()
    const post = await s3.createPresignedPost({
      Bucket: 'waveforms',
      Key: `voicememo/${req.query.file}`,
      ContentType: 'audio/mpeg',
      ACL: 'public-read',
      Expires: 60
    })
    res.status(200).json(post
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: e.message })
  }
}
```

**It currently returns a 400 Bad Request error.**

---

This is an alternative solution, which **does** upload an MP3 successfully to `S3`, however the file is not playing when accessed via the `S3` console, although it does have a `filesize`.

```
module.exports = requireAuth(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_1,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      region: 'us-east-2',
      signatureVersion: 'v4'
    })

    const s3 = new AWS.S3();

    const uuid = randomUUID()
    const s3Params = {
      Bucket: 'waveforms',
      Key: `voicememo/${uuid}.mp3`,
      Body: req.body,
      ContentType: 'audio/mp3',
      ACL: 'public-read'
    }

    await s3.upload(s3Params).promise()
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: e.message })
  }
})
```

And this is the accompanying fetch request.

```
const submitVoiceMemo = async () => {
    try {
      await fetch('/api/createVoiceMemo', {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: audioBlob
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the value of `blob.type`?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary `console.log(typeof audioBlob) returns object`

Comment: Try hardcoding it to `"audio/mpeg"`

Comment: I tried that too, the new `API` (see above) is uploading files to `S3` now, however they are not playable... I think the problem is extracting `audioBlob` from the incoming `string` to the `API` (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271618/how-to-send-audio-video-data-uri-from-browser-to-a-file-in-s3). If I try to destructure `req.body.audioBlob` it returns undefined.

Comment: Don't use a form body and just extract the blob before sending it to the API.

Comment: Yes, in the revised `Fetch` request, I'm sending `audioBlob` directly to the `API`.

Comment: Your question is now changing shape again  I would advise deleting both and putting your final one down; there's not really much value to be derived from these 2 as they are more your experimentation :)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary New question! :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71726800/audio-files-stored-in-s3-are-not-playable.